# Detect if window has scrollbar in IE using javascript (window.open)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scrollbar

When i call window.open, I can include a list of parameters. One of these paramaters is scrollbars, which can be set to *yes* or *no*.

When I put javascript in the child window, the javascript needs to detect if scrollbars were set to yes or no when the window was opened. I want to know if the window has scrollbars enabled by default or not.

I only care about doing this in IE. How do I check? window.scroolbar does not work in IE.

How do I do this? To be perfectly clear, I'm not talking about div overflows, I'm talking about the scrollbar property of the window.

edit:
- I am in IE so window.scrollbars/this.scrollbars won't return anything
- The windows scrollbars exist outside the body.
- Looking at the document's width will tell me about the document. I can even figure out if there are scrollbars in the document. This will not tell me anything about the window itself.
- The width of the window's scrollbar changes dependent on what the currently selected Windows Desktop Theme is, for ascetic reasons.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you need to know this? If you explain the use case, there may be a better way around the problem.

Comment: @Paul Manzotti: I have a method that resizes the window based on its body size. IE reports the total expected width of the window without scrollbars. The resize method changes the width *with scrollbars taken into account*. So it could say the expected width is 100 but you'll need to resize to 108 to make it work right  (or more depending on the currently selected windows theme which affects scrollbar width. Vista theme's scrollbars is wider than xp's, for example). If there are no scrollbars, I don't need to add this width to resize properly.

Comment: I suppose that my question here would be why the variation in whether scrollbars have been turned off or not? Are you not controlling that?

Comment: @Paul Manzott: There are scrollbars caused by divs and there's a scrollbar attached to the window itself. Both can exist or neither. The div scrollbars can be reported by javascript and manipulated via overflow/whatever. The scrollbars on the window are created by window.open. The parent page created the window. Sometimes it uses scrollbars, sometimes it doesn't. When the child window opens, it has its own html and javscript. When I'm in the child window, I need to know if scrollbars exist. The parent did know at one point, but I'm not sure how to use this to my advantage at the moment.

Comment: I don't want to depend on looking at my parent's values either, because that means if somebody else opened my page as a window, I won't be able to get the appropriate values. I don't like relying on assumptions.

Comment: +1 because that's a good question.  Finding the actual window width, not just document.documentElement.clientWidth is rather hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine if the window has a visible scrollbar in IE by using this little JavaScript trick:

```
//You'll have to modify this so as not to do it unless your user is running IE
window.attachEvent('onload', getChrome);

function getChrome() {
    //read the window width and height
    var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    //set the window to that size
    window.resizeTo(w, h);

    //read the window width and height again
    var newW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var newH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    //calculate the difference
    var diffX = w - newW;
    var diffY = h - newH;

    //set the window back to what it was
    window.resizeBy(diffX, diffY);

    alert('diffX: ' + diffX + '\ndiffY: ' + diffY);

    //If diffX is larger than 10 (in Vista and Windows 7, the borders are 5px each)
    //then you're scrollbar is visible.
}
```

Comment: This is very clever, though technically the most complicated. It looks like I hit "mark as answer" a few seconds too late :-/ It auto-marked without my intervention because my time expired.

Comment: For the record, this is what I used and it works fine with one exception - if the user has the left mouse button down window.resizeby will not fire. We added some workarounds to this limitation and everything functions as desired.

Answer (score 8):

Alongside your script that opens the child window (the one where you set scrollbars=yes or no), add a window-level variable that's true if scrollbars=yes, or false if no.

Then in your child window's script, you look up the value that's been set from `self.opener.myWindowLevelVariable`.

You could also namespace the variable. The important part is self.opener or window.opener if you prefer.

**Update:**

In response to your update about not wanting to use a variable in the parent...Then reverse my initial suggestion. Put the variable in the child when it's created.

Parent:

```
var scrollwindow = window.open("file.htm", "anotherwindow", "width=400,height=250,scrollbars=no");
scrollwindow.hasScrollbars = false;
```

Child:

```
alert(hasScrollbars);
```

If you want to handle the case where the child window is opened directly, then it gets more interesting...

Child:

```
try {
    // do something with hasScrollbars
    // If it isn't true or false, ie undefined, using it will throw you into the catch.
    alert(hasScrollbar);
} catch (e) {
    // scrollbars weren't explicitly added or forbidden, so they'll automatically
    // show up if the content is larger than the window. In this case, use a
    // scrollbar sniffing technique.
    var hasVerticalScrollbar = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.clientHeight;
    var hasHorizontalScrollbar = document.body.scrollWidth > document.body.clientWidth;
}
```

**Scrollbar sniffing:** I think this is what Stephano was going for. He was on the right track. But use clientWidth, scrollWidth, clientHeight, and scrollHeight in combination. From [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html):

> If the element has no scrollbars
>   scrollWidth/Height should be equal to
>   clientWidth/Height.
>
> When the element has no scrollbars IE makes the scrollHeight
>   equal to the actual height of the
>   content; and not the height of the
>   element. **scrollWidth is correct,
>   except in IE8, where it’s 5 pixels
>   off.**

So, you'll have to adjust the scrollbar sniffing part a bit for IE, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed post. I'll be able to test this Monday morning. I gave you an upvote to be sure you get credit for your post if I don't "mark as answer" in time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky, but it seems to work:

```
function has_scrollbar() { 
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight < document.body.offsetHeight) {
        alert("vertical scrollbar");
    } else {
        alert("no vertical scrollbar");
    }
}
```

You check the size of the offsetHeight (html content) and compare it with the documentElement.clientHeight (window height for IE).  You can switch out "width" for "height", obviously.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in IE.

window.scrollbars and this.scrollbars is not supported in ie

Comment: Ah wonderful.  You can always count in IE :) .  What version are you using?

Comment: IE7 or IE8 under IE7 compatibility mode. 

IE8 standard mode has hard crashes with certain types of valid html (caused by two stylesheet bugs giving conflicting orders), so we always force compatibility mode.

Comment: edited the code.  if you put that in the "popup window" it should tell you if it has a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: I'm afraid that only tells me the document width. It doesn't take into account that little gray bar to the left of IE that lets you resize the window or the scrollbar to the right. When you call window.resize it takes both of those to account, so i need to know the actual window width, not just the width of the document inside the window before the application adds padding.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [document height](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/), then check [window height](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) and if document height is a bigger number, then you have scrollbars.

However, because IE will display always scrollbars (even if you don't have anything to scroll) you may want to set `overvlow:auto` for body tag.

Comment: As both my original post and the linked site included state, IE does not support window height directly. It tells you the body height, which is not what I was asking for. There's a difference between the body having a scrollbar and the window having one. They can both have scrollbars or neither. I dont' care about the body, i just care about the widnows. This is not always on. it is set by window.open and cannot be changed.

Comment: I guess you cannot have scroll if the document height is bigger than window height...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scrollwindow = window.open("file.htm", "anotherwindow", "width=400,height=250");
  if (scrollwindow.scrollbars) 
  {
alert("Yes we have  scrollbars");
  }
 else 
{
    alert("Sorry doesnt support scrollbars");
  }
```

Comment: While that explains how to check from the parent window, how can the child check? I'm talking about javascript that's present in file.htm